# Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to only same domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cpanel

Using .htaccess or Apache in cPanel, is it possible to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to only its own domain globally across all sites served in cPanel?

Something like:

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "SAMEDOMAIN"

I see tons of examples on allowing domains, but how to just allow the domain serving the request?

or is there a way to disable this altogether?

Comment: I don't understand - if you are only making requests to the same domain, then it is _not_ cross-origin ... so what would you need CORS for in the first place ...?

Comment: In Wordpress the  wp-json API is open to CORs need this disabled globally. Even though you can disable the rest API the route remains open Cross domain.

Comment: _"In Wordpress the wp-json API is open to CORs need this disabled globally"_ - so you mean you want to turn this feature _off_ actually? Then you should use `Header unset`, rather than trying to change the value.

Comment: Just header unset?  Noting else? Basically I need the API so it doesn't respond from any other domain.

Comment: That doesn't need CORS, so it doesn't need any `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.